# Dynamic motd message from remote source?

Tags: linux, login

*motd* allows to display welcome login messages for Linux users.

Is it possible to configure motd in a way to fetch some remote URL?

Example scenario:

- inform users about Python 2 end of life, but stop doing so as the deadline is passed.
- suppress this message if no Python2 is installed

More complex scenario examples:

- pass an argument, evaluate it dynamically and inform user that this OS is no more supported.

Answer (score 1):

For system-wide messages, the motd could be generated at boot time – which is how Ubuntu and Debian currently do it. They have an `update-motd` system which assembles the text file from a standard header, tips, announcements, system update messages, and so on.

In most cases, the motd is shown by a PAM module named `pam_motd`. (The Debian/Ubuntu system actually works by calling the module twice – first for the static /etc/motd, then for the autogenerated /run/motd.)

So if you need more dynamic text (e.g. based on the logged-in username), you could create your own version of this module and make it do anything you want.

However, *do not* make it retrieve files from the web directly, as that'll just slow down logins and annoy your users every time. Instead set up a cronjob that downloads the file, then simply call the existing pam_motd module with the file name as a parameter:

```
session optional pam_motd.so motd=/tmp/downloaded_message.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/motd` is just a static text file.

What you're talking about sounds more like something that could be implemented with a login script.

Newer Linux distributions tend to have an `/etc/profile.d` directory, to which you could just drop in script snippets to be executed as a user logs in. To cover all common shells, you should produce two variants of such script snippets: one compatible with POSIX `/bin/sh` with a `.sh` suffix, and another using `csh` syntax with a `.csh` suffix.

For older distributions, you could add your desired functionality to `/etc/profile` and `/etc/csh.login` (for all POSIX `sh`-compatible shells and for `csh`/`tcsh` shells, respectively).

You could certainly make a script that contacts a specific remote URL and adds some relevant system information as e.g. custom HTTP headers, which the remote end could parse and respond with a tailored message text.

However, if the response returned from the remote URL is not just plain text but contains potentially executable content, this mechanism becomes security-sensitive: if the server containing the remote URL (or the network, or the login script itself) is not secure, it could become a way for an intruder to gain access to your system. You would have to be way more careful in your implementation to prevent that.

You should also think of what happens if the remote URL turns out to be unreachable, or the network link is down: you'll want the message system to time out and continue the login in most error situations.